# View jspm global link cache

Tags: jspm

As per [Linking | JSPM](http://jspm.io/docs/linking.html), you can add a local package to the global link cache,

```
cd my-local-package
jspm link github:my/repo@dev
```

Is there a way to view all the links in this global cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could find is that all these links are stored at `~/.jspm/linked`